# npm ERR! 404 Not Found for Private Package while installing on gitLab CICD

Tags: node.js, npm, cicd

I have created a private package on npm and installed on locally it's working fine. During deployment of the project with GitLab CICD. I am getting this error. To resolve this I created a `.npmrc` file in build with access token as.

script:

```
  whoami
  echo $PATH
  source /etc/environment
  echo '//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=<MY_AUTH_TOKEN>'>.npmrc
  npm whoami
  npm i
```

Error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET
https://registry.npmjs.org/@<MY_ORG>/<PRIVATE_PACKAGE_NAME>/-/<PRIVATE_PACKAGE_NAME>-1.0.1.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@<MY_ORG>/<PRIVATE_PACKAGE_NAME>@1.0.1' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'app'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-09-22T17_46_52_727Z-debug.log
```

Please help me out to fix this issue.

Comment: Does `npm whoami` return the expected result?

Answer (score 1):

Double-check your npm token. In your npm account profile.

Each `npm logout` actually deletes the token from your account. (stored in global .npmrc on your machine).